# Android - How to create clickable listview?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, clickable

I want to make all my list items in the listview open up into a new page, so each listview item opens up onto a new black page that I can use. I don't know how to implement this at all. I have searched for hours on end and can't find an answer to my solution. It would be much appreciated if someone could show and/or explain how to do this instead of providing a link, but either is helpful.

Here is my code so far:

```
  <string-array name="sections">
    <item >Pro Constructive</item>
    <item >Con Constructive</item>
    <item >1st Speaker Cross</item>
    <item >Pro Rebbutal</item>
    <item >Con Rebuttal</item>
    <item >2nd Speaker Cross</item>
    <item >Pro Summary</item>
    <item >Con Summary</item>
    <item >Grand Cross</item>
    <item >Pro Final Focus</item>
    <item >Con Final Focus</item>
</string-array>
```

This is in my string.xml

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/sections" >
</ListView>
```

This is in my activity_main.xml.

Where do I go from here to make each item in my list clickable and able to open up onto a new page?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Logcat no longer relevant.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In fact it is quite easy:

This is your Activity with the ListView, it implements an OnItemClickListener:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //* *EDIT* * 
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
            // Then you start a new Activity via Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, ListItemDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            // Or / And
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Edit**

The above code would be placed in your MainActivity.java. I changed the name of the class to `MainActivity` and the contentView to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` - The names are those of a freshly created Android Project in Eclipse. 
Please see also the 2 new lines under //* *Edit* * - those will set the Listener for clicks on items in the list.

Your activity_main.xml should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/sections" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The **array.xml** (not string.xml) in your `res/values/` folder looks like this

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="sections">
        <item >Pro Constructive</item>
        <item >Con Constructive</item>
        <item >1st Speaker Cross</item>
        <item >Pro Rebbutal</item>
        <item >Con Rebuttal</item>
        <item >2nd Speaker Cross</item>
        <item >Pro Summary</item>
        <item >Con Summary</item>
        <item >Grand Cross</item>
        <item >Pro Final Focus</item>
        <item >Con Final Focus</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

N.B.: If you copy & paste this code it should work. But you will get an error by clicking on an Item because you haven't created the `ListItemDetail.class` yet.

Here is an example of how this could look:

Your ListItemDetail.java:

```
public class ListItemDetail extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listitem);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    // Here we turn your string.xml in an array
    String[] myKeys = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections);

    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    myTextView.setText(myKeys[position]);


    }

}
```

And its activity_listitem.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_textview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you copy past this code it will work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this. Would I place this in the string.xml or activity_main.xml, and would I be replacing anything in this with my own information?

Comment: Okay so like you said, it gives me an error, but I did add the activity_listitem.xml and ListItemDetail.java and I don't know why the app FC's, especially because I have no errors.

Comment: You did create the array.xml file in /res/values/ - Without error it's just guessing : / Tried my code again in eclipse and it works

Comment: To make it easier i zipped the files: http://ego.lu/stuff/listview.zip - Scan with www.virustotal.com to be sure it's save ;) - The .java files and the .xml files are in there

Comment: Alright, I'll compare yours to mine and report back later. Thanks for even doing this though, you've been a real help.

Comment: Oh and verify you have included the class in your manifest: `<activity android:name=".ListItemDetail"></activity>` (I might have left it named TextActivity)

Comment: I added my logcat error for you to see. Maybe I need to declare something in the Manifest?

Comment: Ok so I verified the class in my manifest like you said, and that fixed the problem except for that now my array doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

you can populate listview from array in string.xml as like this

```
String[] myKeys = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections);
ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myKeys));
```

and clicking on the listview items is quite simple and easy method.just use [setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
    {

        Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yourclass.class);
        n.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(n);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

- List item

  ```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          if(position==0){
              Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main3Activity.class);
              startActivity(i);
          }
      }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `onListItemClick` function to set up your Intent that loads the next activity and passes any data across.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside fragment.java with Array Adapter

String[] menuItems = {"Default C02", "Default 02 "};

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.main_menu);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity()
        ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
        ,menuItems
    );

    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id){
            Log.i("menuItems", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);



        }
    });
```