# Clickable listview in fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to create a simple clickable listview in a fragment. (not a listfragment)
So when you click a item it goes to a new detailpage about that item.

I got the listview working but I cant seem to figure out how to get the items clickable. I am very new to android programming..

My application is seperated in 4 tabs, this is one of them.

The question is: How do I make items in a listview (in a fragment) clickable?

My fragment class:

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;

  public class BiblioFragment extends Fragment {

final String[] items = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
   "Linux", "OS/2" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biblio, container, false);

    ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;       
}
```

}

XML

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281197/android-how-to-create-clickable-listview

Comment: That's not a listview in a fragment right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an OnItemClickListener to your list.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Log.v("TAG", "CLICKED row number: " + arg2);
        }

    });
```

The row you clicked is in arg2.

Comment: Can you add this to my main code? Because I get 'Unreachable code' error.

Comment: Just add this after list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Worked. And then from now on I can make an if statement where arg2 = 1 start this activity, when arg2 = 6 start this activity, etc.? Right? Or is there a easier way around this? Because this would mean I have to create x number of activities for every detail page.

Comment: Well yes, but a better aproach is to just have one activity that handles all your scenarios. Pass the arg2 int as an intExtra and let the receiving activity figure out what do with it. This won't work though if your activities are completely different for each item you click, then you will have to go the way you said.

Comment: So if I understand completely.. On this details page I check what number is in arg2 and then with setText change text for example?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biblio, container, false);

ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

return view;
```

}