# General - Understanding fragments and methodologies in using them in apps

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, webview

I have created several apps with simple activities, primarily for and developed with the SDK for android 2.3.3 - the OS my tablets is on.
This is good because on newer devices they (should) work.

Now I'm moving onto android 4.3+ devices (my new tablet) and I am creating an app to make use of the big real estate of the tablets.

I'm trying to understand fragments. The Developers guide is good, but as I'm developing for tablets and large screen devices specifically, I'm wondering if I should be using fragments at all?

Scenario:
I am displaying a Listview that has options. Each option updates the same Listview with another set of options, and so on, until the user has selected the final options (three nested options levels). With each Listview select, there may be default values, and the webview to the immediate right of the Listview is updated. So you can add granularity to the options.
To get back to the default options you can click the menu to return to the "main menu".

In this scenario, I don't want every click to open the webview  (as per the examples here in stack overflow that I've seen, and in the developer guide, as the program wont be available for phones - only tablets.

Apart from the Navigation Drawer fragment menu and the actionbar menu, can anyone advise why it is best practice to use fragments in this example?
Can you point me to a guide that advises why you would use fragments when you want to display  a listview and webview side by side?

I've done so much reading and examples, but I still cant see a benefit apart from being "the done thing". I still see a simple layout y with listvew and webview being updated on every click as the simplest option with less overheads...

Id like to educate myself in learning OS 4 programming techniques, but I'm struggling to see any benefit to this...

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, fragments help reduce the number of activities in your apps, adapt easier to many screen sizes, and boost the reusability.

For example: You have a `Listview` and a `Webview` in a layout for tablet. Now what should you do if people install it on a smaller screen size that can only display either a `ListView` or a `WebView` at a time. For developers who don't use fragment, they have 2 options:

1. Open another activity (`webview`) when users click on an Item on the list.
2. Refresh the layout.

For both cases, it is not as convenient as using fragments.

> Fragments simplify the reuse of components in different layouts, e.g.,
>   you can build single-pane layouts for handsets (phones) and multi-pane
>   layouts for tablets. This is not limited to tablets; for example, you
>   can use fragments also to support different layout for landscape and
>   portrait orientation on a smartphone.
>
> As it is possible to dynamically add and remove fragments from an
>   activity, the usage of fragments allows to design very flexible user
>   interfaces.
>
> The typical example is a list of items in an activity. On a tablet you
>   see the details immediately on the same screen on the right hand side
>   if you click on item. On a smartphone you jump to a new detail screen.

From [Fragment Advantage](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_usage)

Comment: So, from my understanding, and the examples I have seen, if I want to replace the listview with another adapter (simple in non fragments but Ive had no end of trouble in fragments), I should be replacing the whole fragment? Also, Im usnig app v7 support so Im using ActionBarActivity as per (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html). so are the calls the same? What function do I need to override to include calls to pressing the listview items?

Comment: ...cont. OnItemSelected doesnt seem to work in fragments, I believe there is no link to the viewroot class... or should I post code and details in another question? (this is a general question that I cant find the functionality in the develop site... sorry.)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. `ListView` cannot be replaced by an `Adapter`. You can create another adapter and set to the same listview. You can have many fragments in one layout, and you can choose which one to show. So I think you do not need to replace anything.

Comment: Sorry, a badly worked phrase. I am updating listview by replacing the contents of the adapter. Calling this inside an activity is fine (the FindViewById() function works, but not inside a fragment (the listview is inside the fragment, so I dont know where to call it from. I can populate the listview for the intial value but I cant update it when the listview item is clicked....FindViewById returns null. Or should I start another question? (I only want pointers to functions I should be overriding, not examples of code...) Thanks.

Comment: So the problem is your code, not fragment. You can paste your code in your question or open a new one. Probably your problem looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313070/clickable-listview-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in software engineering, like most other engineering disciples, you want your design to be the simplest design that will accomplish the goal.

If your UI is going to be the same on every device it runs on, then you are right; maybe there is no compelling reason to use fragments and you should just stick to activities.

But if you are learning to write tablet apps, you have to come to grips with the reality that over 80% of Android screens are 5" and smaller.  Fragments are essential to modern apps that handle multiple screen sizes.  If one of the purposes of your application is to learn how to develop tablet apps, why not take this opportunity to learn how to use fragments? Because sooner or later, you will need to know how...

Comment: Thanks Kris Larson and Nguyen Doan Tung for your answers. That is what I thought but wanted others opinions... Very Much Appreciated!