# Android Buttons Overlap Each Other (Correct Answer Found)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I just have a small question about android button layout. I have buttons in my app that I have set to -5dip on all 4 sides. I know I can mess around with the numbers but all I want to do is have them fill a spot right next to each other with no overlap. I am very new to app building and any help would be nice.

My .xml file that is being referenced.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_menuScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.comprehensivezeldachecklist.MainMenu$PlaceholderFragment" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <!-- Zelda -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/Zelda" />
        <!-- Zelda II -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:text="@string/Zelda2" />
        <!-- A Link to the Past -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/LinkToThePast" />    
        <!-- Link's Awakening -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/LinksAwakening" />            
        <!-- Link's Awakening DX -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/LinksAwakeningDX" />    
        <!-- Ocarina of Time -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/OcarinaOfTime" 
            android:onClick= "OoTMenu"/>    
        <!-- Majora's Mask -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/MajorasMask" />    
        <!-- Oracle of Ages -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/OracleOfAges" />    
        <!-- Oracle of Seasons -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/OracleOfSeasons" />    
        <!-- Four Swords -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/FourSwords" />    
        <!-- Master Quest -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/MasterQuest" />    
        <!-- Wind Waker -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/WindWaker" 
            android:onClick= "WWMenu"/>    
        <!-- Four Swords Adventures -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/FourSwordsAdventures" />    
        <!-- Minish Cap -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/MinishCap" />    
        <!-- Twilight Princess -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/TwilightPrincess" />    
        <!-- Phantom Hourglass -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/PhantomHourglass" />
        <!-- Spirit Tracks -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/SpiritTracks" />
        <!-- Skyward Sword -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/SkywardSword" />
        <!-- Ocarina of Time 3D -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/OcarinaOfTime3D" />
        <!-- Wind Waker HD -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/WindWakerHD" />
        <!-- Link Between Worlds -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:text="@string/LinkBetweenWorlds" />
    </LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

Here is what I mean when I say they overlap each other:

[image: Overlap]

Comment: Why -5dp? That is what is making the overlap. Why not zero dp?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier When I set them to 0dip they have the white background showing. I want them to butt up against each other without showing background or overlap. I didn't know if there was an easy way to do that.
[Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106195289/Screenshot_2014-05-25-02-50-21.png)

Comment: `When I set them to 0dip they have the white background showing`..dint get you...

Comment: @Lal Here is what I mean. [Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106195289/Screenshot_2014-05-25-02-50-21.png)

Comment: check if there is any padding given for your first 2 buttons...

Comment: I want them to fill up all that empty space without overlapping each other. I can mess with the numbers but I thought maybe there would be a different, easier, more efficient way.

Comment: try removing `android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"` from all your buttons..

Comment: Check your java class whether it contains anything like `setPadding` or so...

Comment: Done. Nothing happened. They look exactly the same.

Comment: Did you check your java file????

Comment: Yes and no padding anywhere in the java file

Comment: By the way I really appreciate the help even if a solution can't be found.

Comment: Your xml is correctly working for me...May be You are specifying padding somewhere in your code..Look your java code for that thoroughly..please...

Comment: the android default button view is with the spaces. meaning the image contains the space in them. if you want buttons without any spaces (and not set margin to -5) you will have to draw the buttons yourself

Comment: May i give you a solution...You divide the vertical linear layouts into the number of buttons you need and set height and width of buttons to fill_parent..this will solve the issue..

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I knew there had to be a way to do it. I will try it and see how it looks. Thank you.

Comment: the extra space comes from this https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_normal.9.png

Comment: I get it. So as @amirye was suggesting I could draw my own button with no transparent space surrounding it. Then I could have it be at 0dp and have them touching, but not overlapping, each other.

Comment: Yes I could. I have a few solutions to try out and see what I like best. I assumed buttons would be the way to go. A clickable list view might not be a terrible idea either. It all depends on how good I want to app to look and if I even decide to upload it to the market when it is complete (only if it looks and runs decent).

Comment: More than anything I am making the app for my personal use and was going to share it if others wanted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, I found something that is more simple but still does essentially what I wanted to do. Instead of resizing the buttons I could just use a borderless button.

In the .xml file I had to add this line of code to my buttons:

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Making the full code of one of my buttons look like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Zelda"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
```

All I had to do was change the `minSdkVersion` to 11 in the Manifest. (Sorry anyone with an older phone who wants to run this app.)

Here is what it looks like now:

[image: borderless button style]

Answer (score -1):

You should use ListView instead and then set onClick function that will take care of each and every option.
Here is a good example of how to do it:
[Android - How to create clickable listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281197/android-how-to-create-clickable-listview)

Comment: I might give that a try. I didn't know a clickable list view was possible.

Comment: If you need help just comment and when i get home i will show you Blog Reader app i did using ListView of blog titles that i implemented to be clickable, it will take me few hours so just post here and i will do my best to give you that as fast as possible.BTW, why the thumpbs down?

Comment: I will let you know how it goes if I end up needing help. I appreciate the help, a lot. Like I mentioned above this is an app for personal use and it will only hit the market once it is much better. I assumed buttons were the best choice but a clickable listview is an option. As for the thumbs down idk, I can't vote up or down with my current rep. I thought it was a viable solution.