# Android: make a single item in a listview clickable

Tags: java, android

I currently have a `ListView` `id=listview`, which I am populating with an `ArrayList` `id=myarraylist`. Here is how I do it:

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
myarraylist = (ArrayList<String>) getArray();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist);

myarraylist.add(...And then some other stuff I add...);

//This is the part I want to focus on
myarraylist.add("Reset High Scores");

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, I want the entry `Reset High Scores` in my `ListView` to be clickable, and when it is clicked, I want it to do `Some Stuff`. I know for buttons all you do is set an onClickListener

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ..Some Stuff..

    }
});
```

My question is, how can I make `Some Stuff` happen when the element `Reset High Scores` is clicked in the `ListView`

**Edit**: This is what I have so far

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            @Override               
            String myString = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            if(myString.equals("Clear High Scores")) {

                //Stuff

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: I think what you need is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13281256/3640637

Comment: @PedroHawk I was looking at this a moment ago, but I think this example is for clicking anywhere on the ListView, instead of a particular location

Comment: then you can use POSITION parameter to verify if your `myarraylist.get(POSITION)`  is equal to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView`, just like `Button`, has the ability to set a click listener, but for `ListView`, the name of the method is `setOnItemClickListener()`.  Instead of using `OnClickListener`, though, it uses a class called `OnItemClickListener`, which is more advantageous for using with `ListView`.  The method looks as follows:

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // some stuff
        }
    }
)
```

Now the advantage of this is that you can check what's contained at the position you've pressed, so the way you could tackle your problem could look something like this:

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
            View view, int position, long id)
    {
        String myString = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        if(myString.equals("Reset High Scores"))
        {
            // Do what you want
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Cool, but how would this method know that `listview` was being clicked? Would I have to use `listview.onItemClick`?

Comment: @user3728164 You have to set the `OnItemClickListener` the same way you would a button.  I've editted my answer to reflect that.

Comment: When I tried this I got the errors `The method onItemClick(new OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type ListView` and `OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: You are using the wrong method.  To set the listener you use `setOnItemClickListener()`, not `onItemClick()`.

Comment: hmm.. now it says `The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})`

Comment: You would have to update your question.  I've checked the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) for `AdapterView` (which is a super class of `ListView`) and the above should be working.

Comment: I updated my question with what I have

Answer (score 0):

```
   /**
 * Creates a new instance
 */
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Notify the parent activity of selected item
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   //Do stuff

}
```

that should get ya started... Andrew is right though.