# Passing object to new activity in a clickable List View

Tags: android, listview

I've implemented a clickable List View using an ArrayAdaptor:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_tasks);

    myTasksListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mytasks_listView);
    myTasksListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    tasks = getTasks(); //of type Task[]
    ArrayAdapter<Task> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tasks);
    myTasksListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TaskDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now, in the new activity I'm starting on item click, I can get the position of the item that was clicked; however, I'm not sure what would be the best method of getting the actual array. Can I

- Find the Activity that launched the new activity and then access the ArrayAdaptor from there?
- make my class Task parcelable and then just call intent.putExtra() on my object itself?

or is this another approach that's considered "best practice"? I was trying to follow along [this helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281197/android-how-to-create-clickable-listview) but it looks like the array in question was hard coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to make the `Task` class implement the `Parcelable` interface. If you did so, you'd be able to use [`Intent.putExtra(String, Parcelable[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable[])) and simply call

```
intent.putExtra("tasks", tasks);
```